# помогите с расширением получения айпи

Tags: javascript, jquery, chrome-extension

ребят надо мне написать расширение которое показывает ip пользователя я написал вот так

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $.getJSON("http://jsonip.com/?callback=?", function (data) {
        console.log(data);
        alert(data.ip);
    });
});
```

все работает на обычной странице(если запускать сам файл html) но если через расширение запустить появляется такая ошибка[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Расширение не может обращаться к доменам не текущей страницы, если они не описаны в манифесте в разделе permissions

Comment: не помогло ошибка осталась

Comment: А что вы туда написали, `"permissions": [ "http://jsonip.com/*" ]` ? Если это не помогает, то возможно сервер на котором размещена страница явно запрещает подгрузку из других источников. попробуйте получать ip из background скрипта

Answer (score 1):

Вы пытаетесь получить данные используя JSONP. Такой метод считается небезопасным в контексте расширений, поэтому его исполнение заблокировано (о чем и говорит ошибка).

Решение

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $.getJSON("http://jsonip.com/", function (data) {
        console.log(data);
        alert(data.ip);
    });
});
```

Я убрал `?callback=?` и получил обычный JSON.